# Custom query return

Tags: wp-query

Here is the full code that I am using:

```
<form action ="" method="get">
    <INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="colour" VALUE="red"> Red<BR>
    <INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="colour" VALUE="blue"> Blue<BR>
    <button type="submit" name="">Search</button>
</form>

<?php
    if ( $_GET['colour'] && !empty ($_GET['colour'] ) ) {
        $colours= $_GET['colour']; 
    }

    $meta_query = array( 'relation' => 'OR' );
    foreach ( $colours as $colour ) {
            $meta_query[] = array(
                    'key'       => 'colour',
                    'value'     => $colour, 
                    'compare'   => 'like', 
            );
    }

    $query = new WP_Query( $meta_query );
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
?>
```

Comment: you shouldn't have parenthesis around the value option in your array.  Try removing it.  also, for compare value you could just say '='.

Comment: I replaced LIKE with = and no results were returned, also removed the parenthesis and it didn't like that.  My query looks like this jumpresults/?colour=red&colour=blue  when I select both red and blue checkboxes in the form, individual I get the right results, both together usually only one set of posts.

Comment: oh, i read this wrong maybe.  is $colour an array?  try using 'in' for your compare option.  '=' and 'like' are for strings i believe.  they add wild cards around.    Can you tell me what $colour is returning?

Comment: You probably want to break those apart and do multiple meta_query. Then just add the OR to the list. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35683/meta-query-with-and-or

Comment: Colour is an array yes.  One of the custom fields in a post.  If I have a post  where the field is set to red and another post that is set to blue.  When I run my search with just blue in the query I get the blue post result, same for red.  When I run a query with red and blue I only get one post i.e. blue and not both.

Answer (score 0):

Okay i'm going to try to add this as an answer because I can't do codes in comments:

```
<?php
if($_GET['colour'] && !empty ($_GET['colour']))
{
$colours= $_GET['colour'];  //notice i pluralized.
}
?>  //your code ended php, so i assume there is something here as it is not started again.


$meta_query = array('relation' => 'OR');
foreach ($colours as $colour) {
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'       => 'colour',
        'value'     => $colour, //not sure why you have parentheses, but try with and without here i guess
        'compare'   => 'like',  //switched back out of in because we are out of the array
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I updated my code but now get a Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() error on my page.  Tried a couple of different scripts but still unable to pull the information correctly.